# cmake cannot find static library

Tags: c++, cmake

g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2

I have a static library called sdpAPI.a

I am trying to link my cpp file to it using cmake.

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this?

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(demo_project CXX)

IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -O0 -D_DEBUG -ggdb -m32")
ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(sdpapi)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(~/projects/test_sdp/sdpapi)

SET(source_files main.cpp)
SET(libs sdpAPI)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(demo ${source_files})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(demo ${libs})
```

And my sdpAPI.a is located in this directory test_sdp/sdpapi/sdpAPI.a

The error I am getting is the following:

```
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/demo.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable demo                                                                                                                                   
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsdpAPI                                                                                                                             
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [demo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/demo.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone see anything obvious that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Had the same error. Solved it by adding:
`add_subdirectory(LibrarySubDir)`
to my CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I should have renamed `sdpAPI.a` to `libsdpAPI.a`

This solved my problem. A silly mistake which cost me 3 hours.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I was just typing that answer.  Anytime gcc looks for a library with the -l flag, it expects to find a library in the form of lib(name).a

Comment: Thanks for that comment. I will remember that in the future.

Comment: thank you, finding this entry saved me some time!

Answer (score 4):

Additional advice for previous answer.

To understand what's going on with compilation/linking just run make with VERBOSE=1 option to see full command used by make.

And of course link options for [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

Answer (score 2):

Use `$ENV{HOME}` instead of `~`.